# How to add jvmArgs using kotlin dsl?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I need to open some javafx modules and I'm told to put it in the `build.gradle.kts`. I have no idea how to add jvmArgs to the run task with the kotlin DSL? Can someone show me how please.

Comment: Do you mean `run` task of Gradle application plugin?

Comment: Yes I believe so :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure default JVM arguments with [`JavaApplication`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaApplication.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaApplication:applicationDefaultJvmArgs) extension:

```
plugins { application }

...

application {
  applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Xmx2048m")
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the `=` sign otherwise I gota "java invalid maximum heap size" error on startup

Answer (score 0):

For just test you can do:

```
tasks {
    test {
        jvmArgs("--arg1", "arg1val")
    }
}
```